# Why Would An Extended Web Application Using Custom Branding Display Differently To It's Parent?

Tags: page-layout, branding

I have an extended web application using branding from a farm solution (wsp). The extended application is displaying a different layout than the one it was extended from. This is a publishing site and the pages have been published but the issue remains.

Comment: Hi Laz, could you clarify your question so we know what you are asking?

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have absolute url:s in your branding solution to register different assets like css files etc. This could be an issue because extended webapp have different host url.

Comment: Hi Tim, the issue is that a box on the page is appearing in the wrong column on the extended page. It was an issue that fixed previously in the test environment, but now once deployed and the application extended, the fix isn't appearing on the extended application, only the parent. Puzzling.

Comment: You said fixed and deployed, was this done via feature? Was that feature deployed to the newly extended web application?

Comment: It was done through a farm solution (wsp) (a bit new to SharePoint, forgive me). I don't have a way to deploy to the extended application, the only one I can deploy to is the main application, the extended applications name does not even show up in the list.